# How I know if the script works from within a subdirectory or not?

Tags: php, subdirectory

In some cases some of us prefer to insert the script into sub-directory, ex: `http://example.com/Script/index.php`, and some others prefer to insert the script into root directory ex: `http://example.com/index.php`.

How to know if the script inside a subdirectory or not ?

Comment: by looking at the url or file path? not really sure what your asking. maybe you want `__DIR__` ?

Comment: @Dagon:I want to know programmatically whether the user has added the script files within a subdirectory or directly to root. Regarding `__DIR__` is not suitable to this work

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should be fairly simple. Bear in mind if `__FILE__` is a symlink it would need some adjustments.

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

/**
 * @var bool TRUE if current script is in DOCUMENT ROOT, FALSE otherwise.
 */
$inRoot = __FILE__ == $root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename(__FILE__);

#OR 
$inRoot = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) == $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately in both cases I get the same result -> `false`.

Comment: It works for me. Pretty sure you're doing something wrong. Have you seen `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` value? Can you debug each part of above script? Anyway, I think you got the point! ;)

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ` = `C:/Program Files (x86)/wamp/www`  
, `__FILE__` = `C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\script\system\Router.php`.

Comment: I think I have found the solution: `echo (dirname(ltrim($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/')) !== '.')? "The script in subdirectory" : "The script in root";`

Answer (score 0):

...or perhaps you can try getcwd(). Returns the current working directory on success, or FALSE on failure.

Comment: I thank you, but when I use `getcwd()` and the script in subdirectory, the result become `C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\script`, while if the script in the root the result become `C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www `. as you have seen in the second result although the script in the root but the result not `false` as expected